# Unable to change date in html 5 input type="datetime"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, datetime, datepicker

I had an html5 input type="datetime" datepicker in a text field.When I click on text field a packer picker opens and after clicking on one date,it closes and date is displayed there.Now I want to change the date and click on the same textxfield the date picker dont open.Again if I do a right click somewhere outside of text field and then click on it,the datepicker opens up...How can we get rid of and display on first click itself..Is there any attribute for doing so.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
<input class="form-control" type="datetime" date-time auto-close="true" view="date" 
min-view="date" maxlength="10" format="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model="$root.date" 
value = "{{dateOfBirth}}" readonly>
</div>
```

In inspectmode if i click on textfield it highlights

```
<div date-picker-wrapper>…</div>
```

Once date is selected it goes hidden>can someone help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone help

Comment: remove readonly

Comment: You're using something that wraps the HTML5 datetime input. You'll need to let us know what that is.

Comment: removing readonly doesnt worked

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Iam not wrapping anything.just using the above div

Comment: You may not know it, but you are. You have what appears to be a `date-time` directive applied to that `input`, so I expect that's it. Unfortunately, there are several dozen datepicker directives for angular out there.

Comment: Ok..How can I find where directive might be created

Comment: I cant find anywhere is the whole bunch of code ,this directive

Comment: In other words which library are you using for your date-pickers @HVarma.

Comment: bootstrap.cerulean.min.css.notinuse,
bootstrap.flatly.min.css.notinuse